# In serialization, what is meant by turning an object into a stream of bytes?

Tags: java, serialization

Isn't an object already stored as a bunch of bytes?  Is serialization just a protocol that forces some order to how those bytes are organized when transferred over a network?

Comment: Well, serialization doesn't just transfer a memory image, it does use a known order and protocol for the transfer. [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).  I guess you could say "just forces" although that seems to trivialize the work needed for serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes, everything in a computer is represented as data *somewhere*.  So any in-memory object is "a bunch of bytes".

However, when being used in a live application the state of that object is subject to change.  It's in flux.  And that state can be stored/changed/known/etc. across multiple mediums.

Serialization is the process of capturing the state of an object into some static form which can be persisted to a more static medium.  Specifically this information needs to include everything required to re-create the object at a later time.

It doesn't really matter what the form or medium is.  The data can be raw binary, JSON, XML, text, any custom format, etc.  The storage medium can be a file system, a database, a network connection, active memory, etc.  And it could be stored for milliseconds or for centuries.

---

As an analogy, consider a human being.  There is a lot of information which makes up everything that is "a person".  How would you "serialize" a person?

You could save their DNA sequence to a computer (a simple array of characters would do the trick).  But does that store the state of the person?  You could re-create *a* person from that data, but could you re-create that same person *in the same state*?  No, all of their memories would be lost.

So in attempting to serialize the person, we've discovered that the information which represents the state of a person includes more than the original information which was used to create the person.  That state information is stored in a separate medium during the lifespan of the person and isn't as easily available.  But it would be necessary in order to serialize the person.

Continuing the analogy... consider transporters from Star Trek.  The "object" is a person, and that person is successfully converted into a stream of data which is then re-constructed on the other end of the transfer.  The two transporter systems are separate, simply exchanging information.  This information is enough to re-create the original object the exact state at which it was serialized.

Answer (score 0):

"Serialization" means transforming an object into another state for the purposes of transfer or persistance.

**Isn't an object already stored as a bunch of bytes?** Yes, but that's not the point. The point is for persistance and transference. Take the case of an image: It is one thing in memory, another when saves as a JPEG, and another when saved as a GIF or a TIFF or a BMP.

**Is serialization just a protocol that forces some order to how those bytes are organized when transferred over a network?** See the answer to your first question on the meaning of serialization